# Converting an S4 object into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-s4

I have an S4 object named 'res' which I got while using an R package called RDAVIDWebService. I can't seem to find a way to convert this object into a dataframe in R.

I tried using the function 'as.data.frame(res)' but it throws this error:

```
> as.data.frame(res)
Error in as.data.frame.default(res) : 
cannot coerce class ‘structure("DAVIDFunctionalAnnotationTable", package = "RDAVIDWebService")’ to a data.frame
```

The structure of the object looks like this:

```
> str(res)
Formal class 'DAVIDFunctionalAnnotationTable' [package "RDAVIDWebService"] with 4 slots
..@ Genes     :'data.frame':    3011 obs. of  3 variables:
Formal class 'DAVIDGenes' [package "RDAVIDWebService"] with 5 slots
.. .. ..@ .Data    :List of 3
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3011] "22574630" "3544383" "3544385" "3544382" ...
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3011] "1,2-Dihydroxy-3-keto-5-methylthiopentene dioxygenase, 
putative(LPMP_204190)" "10 kDa heat shock protein(Tc00.1047053508209.100)" "10 kDa heat shock 
protein(Tc00.1047053508209.120)" "10 kDa heat shock protein(Tc00.1047053508209.90)" ...
.. .. .. ..$ : Factor w/ 11 levels "Leishmania braziliensis MHOM/BR/75/M2904",..: 6 10 10 10 
10 10 10 2 6 6 ...
.. .. ..@ names    : chr [1:3] "ID" "Name" "Species"
.. .. ..@ row.names: chr [1:3011] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
.. .. ..@ .S3Class : chr "data.frame"
.. .. ..@ type     : chr "Gene List Report"
..@ Dictionary:List of 10
.. ..$ COG_ONTOLOGY    :'data.frame':   18 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ ID  : chr [1:18] "Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis" "Lipid 
metabolism" "Cell division and chromosome partitioning" "General function prediction only" ...
.. .. ..$ Term: chr [1:18] "" "" "" "" ...
.. ..$ GOTERM_BP_DIRECT:'data.frame':   215 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ ID  : chr [1:215] "GO:0006457" "GO:0051603" "GO:0008152" "GO:0006412" ...
.. .. ..$ Term: chr [1:215] "protein folding" "proteolysis involved in cellular protein 
catabolic process" "metabolic process" "translation" ...
.. ..$ GOTERM_CC_DIRECT:'data.frame':   84 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ ID  : chr [1:84] "GO:0005737" "GO:0016021" "GO:0005634" "GO:0005839" ...
.. .. ..$ Term: chr [1:84] "cytoplasm" "integral component of membrane" "nucleus" "proteasome 
core complex" ...
.. ..$ GOTERM_MF_DIRECT:'data.frame':   222 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ ID  : chr [1:222] "GO:0010309" "GO:0018580" "GO:0051213" "GO:0004298" ...
.. .. ..$ Term: chr [1:222] "acireductone dioxygenase [iron(II)-requiring] activity" 
"nitronate monooxygenase activity" "dioxygenase activity" "threonine-type endopeptidase 
activity" ...
.. ..$ INTERPRO        :'data.frame':   695 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ ID  : chr [1:695] "IPR004313" "IPR011051" "IPR014710" "IPR011032" ...
.. .. ..$ Term: chr [1:695] "Acireductone dioxygenase ARD family" "RmlC-like cupin domain" 
"RmlC-like jelly roll fold" "GroES-like" ...
.. ..$ KEGG_PATHWAY    :'data.frame':   363 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ ID  : chr [1:363] "ldo00071" "ldo00280" "ldo01100" "lmi00280" ...
.. .. ..$ Term: chr [1:363] "Fatty acid degradation" "Valine, leucine and isoleucine 
degradation" "Metabolic pathways" "Valine, leucine and isoleucine degradation" ...
.. ..$ PIR_SUPERFAMILY :'data.frame':   44 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ ID  : chr [1:44] "PIRSF000868" "PIRSF002144" "PIRSF002134" "PIRSF002122" ...
.. .. ..$ Term: chr [1:44] "14-3-3 protein" "ribosomal protein, S19p/S19a/S15e/organellar S19 
types" "ribosomal protein, S13p/S13a/S18e/organellar S13 types" "ribosomal protein, 
S7p/S7a/S5e/organellar S7 types" ...
.. ..$ SMART           :'data.frame':   90 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ ID  : chr [1:90] "SM00883" "SM00101" "SM01386" "SM01387" ...
.. .. ..$ Term: chr [1:90] "SM00883" "14_3_3" "SM01386" "SM01387" ...
.. ..$ UP_KEYWORDS     :'data.frame':   116 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ ID  : chr [1:116] "Coiled coil" "Complete proteome" "Dioxygenase" "Oxidoreductase" 
...
.. .. ..$ Term: chr [1:116] "" "" "" "" ...
.. ..$ UP_SEQ_FEATURE  :'data.frame':   13 obs. of  2 variables:
.. .. ..$ ID  : chr [1:13] "chain:60S ribosomal protein L18" "chain:Probable eukaryotic 
initiation factor 4A" "domain:Helicase ATP-binding" "domain:Helicase C-terminal" ...
.. .. ..$ Term: chr [1:13] "" "" "" "" ...
..@ Membership:List of 10
.. ..$ COG_ONTOLOGY    : logi [1:3011, 1:18] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
.. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : NULL
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:18] "Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis" "Lipid metabolism" 
"Cell division and chromosome partitioning" "General function prediction only" ...
.. ..$ GOTERM_BP_DIRECT: logi [1:3011, 1:215] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
.. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : NULL
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:215] "GO:0006457" "GO:0051603" "GO:0008152" "GO:0006412" ...
.. ..$ GOTERM_CC_DIRECT: logi [1:3011, 1:84] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
.. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : NULL
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:84] "GO:0005737" "GO:0016021" "GO:0005634" "GO:0005839" ...
.. ..$ GOTERM_MF_DIRECT: logi [1:3011, 1:222] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
.. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : NULL
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:222] "GO:0010309" "GO:0018580" "GO:0051213" "GO:0004298" ...
.. ..$ INTERPRO        : logi [1:3011, 1:695] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
.. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : NULL
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:695] "IPR004313" "IPR011051" "IPR014710" "IPR011032" ...
.. ..$ KEGG_PATHWAY    : logi [1:3011, 1:363] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
.. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : NULL
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:363] "ldo00071" "ldo00280" "ldo01100" "lmi00280" ...
.. ..$ PIR_SUPERFAMILY : logi [1:3011, 1:44] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
.. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : NULL
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:44] "PIRSF000868" "PIRSF002144" "PIRSF002134" "PIRSF002122" ...
.. ..$ SMART           : logi [1:3011, 1:90] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
.. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : NULL
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:90] "SM00883" "SM00101" "SM01386" "SM01387" ...
.. ..$ UP_KEYWORDS     : logi [1:3011, 1:116] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
.. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : NULL
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:116] "Coiled coil" "Complete proteome" "Dioxygenase" "Oxidoreductase" 
...
.. ..$ UP_SEQ_FEATURE  : logi [1:3011, 1:13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
.. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : NULL
.. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:13] "chain:60S ribosomal protein L18" "chain:Probable eukaryotic 
initiation factor 4A" "domain:Helicase ATP-binding" "domain:Helicase C-terminal" ...
..@ type      : chr "Functional Annotation Table"
```

Also, is there a generalized way of converting any S4 object into a dataframe without caring about the data inside the object? This is important because the S4 objects I'm fetching with this R package could have varying number of lists/variables/characters inside each of the 4 slots(i.e. @Genes, @Dictionary, @Membership and @type).

Comment: What do you want to be such data.frame? Which columns/rows? How many columns/rows? ... I do not believe S4 methods can be generally converted to data.frames...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following functions can be of help.

```
as.data.frame.DAVIDFunctionalAnnotationTable <- function(x){
  Genes <- x@Genes
  y <- Genes@.Data
  names(y) <- Genes@names
  y
}

extractS4_Dictionary <- function(x) x@Dictionary
extractS4_Membership <- function(x) x@Membership
extractS4_type <- function(x) x@type
```

The call

```
as.data.frame(res)
```

will coerce `res` to a `data.frame`.
The other functions will extract the S4 object's members.

---

The following function will extract the membership for each annotation.

```
membership <- function(x, which){
  y <- as.data.frame(x)
  memb <- extractS4_Membership(x)
  i <- memb[, which]
  y[i, , drop = FALSE]
}

# example usage
membership(res, "COG_ONTOLOGY")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But this doesn't seem to help as my objective is to identify the annotations (e.g. COG_ONTOLOGY, GOTERM_BP_DIRECT, GOTERM_CC_DIRECT etc.) associated with each of the genes. The dataframe contains only the gene IDs and lists of terms present in the annotation categories. Basically, I need the output as row-column format where there would be a column for genes and separate columns for the annotation categories. This will let me identify which genes lack annotations and which do not.

Comment: @AbhishekChowdhury To identify, say, the `COG_ONTOLOGY` associated with each gene, can't you match the `ID` of the df returned by the function to `Dictionary$COG_ONTOLOGY$ID`, and the same for the other annotations?

Comment: The S4 object that I mentioned in my question has 3011 genes but only 18 COG_ONTOLOGY IDs, which means a lot of genes lack COG_ONTOLOGY IDs. Now, how do I identify which COG_ONTOLOGY ID belongs to which gene?